# Will an lvalue to rvalue conversion happen?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, lvalue, rvalue, lvalue-to-rvalue

> C++ Standard (4/5) the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not done on the
>   operand of the unary & operator.

For example:

```
int x;
int *p = &x;
```

In the above case, are `p` are `&x` both lvalues? or What would be an appropriate example?

**Edit:**

What about this?

```
int &r = x;
```

I'm sure there will be no conversion in this statement, but i'm confused how does & operator involve in this?

Comment: there is also an x value. I think the &x is rvalue in the above

Comment: @VJovic: Yes, but this is not about C++11 :P.

Comment: Ok, then never mind the comment

Comment: There is no & operator in your second example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote says that the conversion is not applied on the operand of unary `&` (in this case, `x`). So the operand of `&` is an lvalue.

This is different from, say, the unary `+` operator. If you write `+x`, then lvalue-to-rvalue conversion *is* applied to the sub-expression `x` (with undefined behavior in this case, since `x` hasn't been initialized).

Informally, "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion" means "reading the value".

The quote doesn't say anything about the *result* of `&`, which in fact is an rvalue. In `int *p = &x;`:

- `x` is an lvalue, referring to the variable of that name,
- `&x` is an rvalue, it's part of the initializer (specifically, an *assignment-expression*),
- `p` is neither an rvalue nor an lvalue, because it is not a (sub-)expression. It's the name of the variable being defined. In the C++ declarator grammar it's the *declarator-id* (8/4 in the C++03 standard).

`int &r = x;` doesn't use the `&` address-of operator at all. The `&` character in the declarator is just the syntax meaning that `r` is a reference-to-int, it's not taking the address of `r`. In the C++ declarator grammar, it's actually called the *ptr-operator*.

Comment: Hello. Related: `int m = *pn; // indirection + lvalue-to-rvalue conversion` [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access). I don't get where rvalue is in this statement?? `*pn` is not an rvalue because I can put `*pn = 3;`.

Answer (score 2):

Think of lvalue as storage place and of rvalue as the value to store there. Therefore `*p` is lvalue and `&x` is rvalue. However, & requires an lvalue as operand (x) but the *result* is a rvalue, but this *does not* change `x` itself.

Comment: I didn't downvote. why do you think `&x` is rvalue? The other two answers by @Nawaz and @Kerrek seems to disagree with you.

Comment: When `*p` stores an address and `&x` is the address of `x` then i assume this is an rvalue since this value itself has no address and can't be an lvalue. Or am i wrong? The cited C++ excerpt say's that i am, but then this makes no sense for me.

Comment: I think you're correct. From what I understood, `&x` doesn't make `x` an rvalue because its just the address of x which is considered an rvalue. +1.

Comment: Hello. What about this: `int m = *pn; // indirection + lvalue-to-rvalue conversion` [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access). I don't get where rvalue is in this statement?? `*pn` is not an rvalue because I can put `*pn = 3;`.

Answer (score 1):

The Standard quote basically says the operand on which `&` applies, doesn't become *rvalue*. It remains *lvalue*.

In fact, the operand of `&` cannot be *rvalue*. It has to be *lvalue*, otherwise one would be able to get the address of a temporary object which is not allowed by the Standard:

```
struct A{};

int *addressOfTemporary_int_object = &(int(10)); //error
A *addressOfTemporary_A_object = &A(); //error
```

It is precisely because the operand of `&` has to be *lvalue*, the above expressions are illegal, as the subexpressions `int(10)` and `A()` are *rvalue* expressions, for they create temporary objects.

Also note that even though the subexpression `x` in the expression `&x` is an *lvalue*, the result of applying `&` on `x` is an *rvalue*. That is, the expression `&x` is an *rvalue*, and cannot appear on the right side of assignment operator:

```
&r = whatever; //illegal
```

I hope this helps you understanding the quote.

---

> What about this?
>
> ```
> int &r = x;
> ```

This is okay. Here `&` makes `r`  a reference of object `x`. The `&` is not an *operator* here, and is not associated with the reference `r`, rather it is associated with the type. It is less confusing to write this as:

```
int&  r = x;

//Or if you use typedef as
typedef int& intref;
intref r = x;
```

Comment: "_int(10) and A() are rvalue expressions, for they create temporary objects._" `int(10)` does _not_ create a temporary object.

Comment: @curiousguy: It does. End of the discussion.

Comment: @Nawaz "_It does._" In which language?

Comment: @curiousguy: Quote from the language in which it doesn't.

Comment: @curiousguy: Are those "quotations" from the language? I asked you to quote from the language.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6131/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-nawaz)

Comment: @curiousguy: You've never quoted from the language specification. You explain something which is not in the spec.

Comment: @curiousguy: If you claim something (and at the same time, * intellectually honest*), you would tell me the reference from spec, supporting your claim.

Comment: @curiousguy: which means you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @curiousguy: For God's sake, you really can't give me the reference?

Comment: @curiousguy: The section is too big. Quote statement(s) which support your stance, then I will believe.

Comment: Can **you** give me the reference where it is said that a `int` rvalue can refer to a temporary of type `int`?

Comment: @curiousguy: If there are no temporaries of non-class type, then what does `int const & x = 5` do? And what would `std::cout << &x << std::endl` print?

Answer (score 0):

"On the operand" should refer to the `x` on the right-hand-side. That is, the subexpression `x` in the statement `int *p = &x;` is *not* an rvalue, but rather an lvalue. Contrast this to `int a = b;`, where the subexpression `b` *is* an rvalue (after conversion).

Answer (score 0):

> C++ Standard (4/5) the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not done on the operand of the unary & operator.

This quote is there just to confuse you. It has no other purpose. ;)

The most important quote is (quoting N3242, so the new terminology has "prvalue" instead of rvalue):

> Whenever a glvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), or function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue.

So the language could be described in term of constructs which expect a prvalue and constructs which do not. In particular, operator `&` does not "expect a prvalue" (quite the contrary), so the lvalue-to-rvalue implicit conversion is not necessary and won't be applied.

The standard description is not consistent: it never explicitly says that in `x += y`, the  lvalue-to-rvalue implicit conversion is not applied to `x`, presumably because it extremely obvious. Why the authors felt the need to explicitly say that for `&x`, where it is equaly obvious, is beyond me.

I think these mentions that implicit conversions are **not** applied should be removed. The standard describe what happens, not the (infinitely many) things that do not happen (unless it is extremely surprising that it does not happen).

Implicit conversions are applied only to adjust the "nature" of an expression to the expectation of the context (context can be an expression, statement, declaration, ctor-init-list...).

> What about this?
>
> `int &r = x;`
>
> I'm sure there will be no conversion in this statement,

because no implicit conversion is *needed* here. Implicit conversion are applied only when needed. Reference binding does not expect a rvalue.

> but i'm confused how does & operator involve in this?

It is not.